# Interchange url with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to interchange URL pattern with .htaccess file like

from

```
http://www.example.com/products/c3058/Truck_Tool_Boxes.html
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/Truck_Tool_Boxes/c3058
```

means I want to change following format:

1. Remove category name 'products'.
2. Interchange between id(c3058) with name(Truck_Tool_Boxes).

Here category name, id and products name is dynamic. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ /$2/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

See: [httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Comment: In addition, complete documentation is here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule